# the concept of negative margins - have i understood?

Tags: html, css, margin

i read that negative margin-top and left takes the element and pushes it in this direction. On the other hand negative bottom and right margins draw the rest of the content over the element.

Question

I have a floated element float:right; wrapped in the body tag. Negative left margin will move it to the left.

Negative RIGHT margin wont do anything at all because the document ends where this negative margin starts and there is nothing to draw over the element (or pull over it)?

Am i correct?

Comment: Why did not you test it?

Comment: i did and what i described occures, i dont need a hacky fix though, i want to understand the concept fully.

Comment: Try setting negative right margin with float:right. You'll be surprised ;)

Comment: Negative right and top margins do have effect in my Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/29g39/1/show/

Comment: sime, only the top margin works in your demo, confirming what i said

Comment: @user1721135 But the document overflows the viewport (horizontally). Only a portion of the element is visible (without scrolling).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Correct. I've expanded that into an answer below.

Comment: -1 for not providing some code that shows your test cases and research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people believe the same misconception about negative margins. The behavior you describe tends to match many negative margins cases, but it is explaining them from a flawed perspective. Actually, negative margins have the same effect on *any* side of the box, but not in terms of "move the box" or "draw other content in".

For example, a `left-margin: -20px` means "position the element as if its left edge were 20 pixels inwards from its true left edge". A `right-margin: -20px` means exactly the same thing, but for the right edge.

In the simplistic description you have provided, the negative left margin would indeed shift the element itself leftwards, because its *left edge* is placed adjacent to the previous element's *right edge*, but the browser pretends that our element's left edge is actually moved *rightwards*, so the content of the element itself appears moved *leftwards*.

With the negative right margin, the browser places the next element's *left edge* adjacent to our element's *right edge*, but it pretends that our element's *right edge* is moved *leftwards*, so the next element itself appears moved *leftwards*.

In both cases, the only thing that is changed is the browser's notion of the position of the element's edges.

When you have a right-floated element, the browser will position it so that its right edge will be adjacent to the left edge of the previous right-floated element, or if there is no previous right-floated element, it will be adjacent to the *right* edge of its position parent (which is the closest parent element with a `position` style that is not `static`). In your case you don't have a previous right-floated element, so the browser positions your element so that its *right edge* is adjacent to the parent's *right edge*, but it pretends your element's right edge is moved *leftwards*, so your actual content is moved *rightwards*, protruding outside of the parent element.

[Here is a demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uxuheq/1/edit). The box with the blue border has negative left and right margins. The yellow box inside it represents how the browser considers it — it is narrower than the blue-bordered box, because the negative margins tell the browser to move its edges inwards, eating from the element's actual size. As you can see, its positioning box is placed exactly as any element would be, touching its left and right siblings on both sides. And the actual content extends in both directions by exactly the same amount, because its negative margins are the same. The *perceived* change is that the element itself is moved left due to its left margin, and following content is moved left due to its right margin, but as you can see, in reality, the effect is exactly the same on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

Negative margins will always work on block boxes the same way that positive margins do. They just move a box and/or surrounding boxes in the opposite direction that positive margins do. Heck, negative margins can even [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

If any overflow occurs, then related boxes will adjust and accommodate for this box's movement.

If an element is floated in a certain direction, then a margin on the side that it's being floated towards will have an effect on its own position, and a margin on the opposite site will influence it relatively to any succeeding floats.

> Negative RIGHT margin wont do anything at all because **the document ends where this negative margin starts** and there is nothing to draw over the element (or pull over it)?

No. There is this thing called the [canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#the-canvas), which has a theoretically unlimited amount of space for expansion. Got a margin pushing an element out of the page body or page root? NBD, just expand the canvas in that direction, make a scrollbar in the viewport which is used to display this canvas, and done.

It's the same as if you had a negative margin on an element whose parent has `overflow: auto`, because [the root element itself has `overflow: auto` by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) (since you can't really have stuff visibly overflowing the browser window itself...).

[jsFiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/rXz9w)

Answer (score 0):

Negative right margin sure works! http://fiddle.jshell.net/H6mjC/

Answer (score 0):

also made a fiddle. Of course negative margin is working.

[fiddle with negative margin](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/hVxpF/4/)

[image]

```
enter code here
```